# Fetch get request returns empty headers

Tags: http, cors, fetch, es6-promise

Headers was indeed sent via http:
[image: headers was sent via http]

However, fetch returned empty headers:
[image: empty headers returned by fetch]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that I need to set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to include the headers I would like to expose.